# Debian server is very slow in spite of low CPU, RAM na SWP usage

Tags: debian, performance, samba, lag

From 3 days I experience problems with my debian server. When I stream media with samba transfer is about 20kb/s when it used to about 6 mb/s. Its my home server so its not internet issue. When I ssh to server I experience 3-4 sec lag time when typing (!).

I checked HTOP and RAM CPU SWP usage are less then 10 %. My HDD are relativly cold 35 C. When I restarted it there is no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does vmstat -5 show you ?    Also, do the log files say anything ?  (I'm wondering if the hard drive is dying)

Comment: What's the loadaverage? Is `top` reporting large processes. Do a `ssh -v host` to display some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was demaged Network Card, I just changed Network Card and all is right now, thanks all for help :)

Answer (score 0):

- HD getting full? File fragmentation?
- HD beginning failure?
- Network cables damaged/dirty?
- WiFi interference?
- I don't think the CPU being throttled to a slow frequency would make a difference in file transfers, but...?